# Text cuts off in Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

FINAL EDIT: Okay well a total hack but at the moment I'm like "meh" it works. All I did to fix the issue was add `android:lines="10"` to the TextView and it showed everything like in 2.2 and ICS/JB.  Total hack because it's not abstract at all but whatever :P..Thanks to everyone who helped!

I'm having trouble displaying text in a custom dialog with Gingerbread (API 10). The only text shown is the first line as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oBmP.png). In Froyo, ICS, and JB it displays [with every line of text shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnwiY.png). I believe it's an XML thing, but I'm not sure. Where am I going wrong?

Edit: What I have tried:

-Changing the RelativeLayout to LinearLayout

-Adding in ScrollView

-Putting my string on one line

-using requestLayout() and forceLayout()

-putting the dialog functions in a separate class

-taking out the margins in my button

-using \n instead of HTML

-AlertDialog

-inputType and singleLine XML attributes on my TextView

-I think there's one or two more that I forget..

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dia_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#CCCCD0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dia_text"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbuttongotit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dialog_confirm"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bar"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Code:

```
final Context context = this;
public void addListenerOnRectHelpButton() {

    img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rect_img); 
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {

               //create a new dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialogs);
            dialog.setTitle("Rectangular Area");

            // set the custom dialog text
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dia_text);
            String dialog_rect_txt = "<u>Area of a Rectangular Channel</u><br />" +
                    "Height x Width (H x W)<br />--Example:<br />" +
                    "Height: 3ft,  Width 5ft<br />" +
                    "H x W = 3ft x 5ft = 15ft<sup>2</sup><br />";
            text.setText(Html.fromHtml(dialog_rect_txt));

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogbuttongotit);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();             

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: I suggest using the support library and a dialog fragment instead.

Comment: Or you can simply put your text into scrollView...

Comment: @yahya I have tried putting it in a scrollView, and that hasn't solved the issue :/

Comment: Have you tried the singleLine or inputType XML attributes?

Comment: @Atlos I'm not so sure singleLine would help, because it would only do one horizontal line instead of fitting everything nicely.  But is `android:inputType:"textMultiLine"` what you had in mind for inputType?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm thinking of.  It's a stretch, but worth a try at least.  Doesn't make sense why it would work fine with ICS/JB.

Comment: Okay, so I tried `textMultiLine` and it did nothing, but when I did `textLongMessage` it still cut off after the first line, but it brought more words up to the first line. Yeah, very odd that it's only 2.3.3....and annoying!

Comment: I'm going to try `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage"` and `android:singleLine="false"` right now.

Comment: @Atlos `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage"` and `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` failed. When I took out inputType and only inserted `singleLine="false"`, it didn't work either.  Man, what is wrong?! If 2.3.3 wasn't 64% of the ecosystem I'd have just dropped the issue by now..

Comment: When I had a similar problem, I had to add a "\n" at the end so it wouldn't cut off the last line, lol.

Comment: ...in the end, setting a "lines" parameter is what truly fixed it, so you were right.

Answer (score 0):

Having you tried calling requestLayout() on the TextView?

```
...
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(dialog_rect_txt));
text.requestLayout();
...
```

Comment: it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an AlertDialog instead of building your own?

```
Dialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(
    "Rectangular Area").setMessage(dialogRectText).setPositiveButton(
     "Got It", clickListener).create();
dlg.show();
```

Comment: I tried an AlertDialog, and got the same issue. I also just tried (with an AlertDialog) putting the string with NO new lines and [ended up with this](http://i.imgur.com/iEigT.png).  This means on 2.3 it will not respect either my Custom Dialog or AlertDialog's layout_width/height? Very odd...